# Pagination buttons not showing disabled css

Tags: css

For some reason when it knows the button is supposed to be disabled it shows the css for the `.paginate_button` and then crosses out the css for the `.paginate_button_disabled`. Does anyone know why?

```
.paginate_button_disabled {
    border: 1px solid #F3F3F3;
    color: #CCCCCC;
    margin-right: 2px;
    padding: 2px 5px;
    border: 0;       
}
.paginate_button:hover {
    border:1px solid #52bfea;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #52bfea;
}
.paginate_active {
    padding: 2px 5px 2px 5px;
    margin-right: 2px;
    border: 1px solid #52bfea;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: #52bfea;
    color: #FFF;
}
.paginate_button {
    padding: 2px 5px 2px 5px;
    margin-right: 2px;
    color: #52BFEA;
    border: 1px solid #52BFEA;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are adding `.paginate_button_disabled` to the element without removing `.paginate_button`, you will need to reorder your css.

The `.paginate_button` rule should come first:

```
.paginate_button {
padding: 2px 5px 2px 5px;
margin-right: 2px;
color: #52BFEA;
border: 1px solid #52BFEA;
}
.paginate_button_disabled {
border: 1px solid #F3F3F3;
color: #CCCCCC;
margin-right: 2px;
padding: 2px 5px;
border: 0;       
}
.paginate_button:hover {
border:1px solid #52bfea;
color: #fff;
background-color: #52bfea;
}
.paginate_active {
padding: 2px 5px 2px 5px;
margin-right: 2px;
border: 1px solid #52bfea;
font-weight: bold;
background-color: #52bfea;
color: #FFF;
}
```

The way CSS works, is it cascades down the document. So if they both have the same specificity the CSS rule lower down will win.

Answer (score 1):

If you are just adding the `.paginate_button_disabled` class to the element, without removing the `.paginate_button` class, then the latter would overwrite the disabled rules as it is defined later in the CSS document - they are literally *cascading* styles.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to hide any unnecessary button.

use the following :

```
.paginate_button_disabled {
    display: none;
}
```

in this case previous, next, first and last buttons will be shown only when they are needed.